# How to turn off the "Hey, look at that -- Points!" notifications from Xbox Game Bar?

Tags: pc, xbox-game-bar

Every once in a while on the PC, mostly when I start playing a game but sometimes if I'm not playing anything, I get a little popup from the Xbox Game Bar that says "Hey, look at that -- Points! Get them before they're gone!" with no additional details besides instructions to open the game bar:

[image]

It doesn't seem to be associated with any particular game.

When I open the game bar, there isn't really anything there that has to do with "points":

[image]

This has been going on for about a month now. I don't really care about these points.

My question is: What is this pop-up trying to tell me and, more importantly, how do I make it stop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it you mean the pop-up shown below?

[image]

[It seems](https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftRewards/comments/rn1sb6/comment/ibue45k/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) this **can be turned off using the "*Notify me when I earn Rewards points*" toggle**, which is on the Notifications tab under Settings.

According to [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/all/how-to-disable-claim-your-points-notifications-on/9ddbc650-a271-480a-8731-b137c53aefff), up to at least January 2022 it wasn't possible to turn these off separately, unless all notifications were turned off.

---

[image]

---

The Notifications tab seen in the image above (*Settings* → *Notifications*) is not there any more. I *think* you now have to log in to your Xbox Social Profile, and (de)activate the notifications there, but it's hard to find any information on this as most sources online still refer to the old situation.

Comment: So, I finally captured in a screenshot, it's [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nR4k.png). From your answer, I found the notifications bell on the XBox Social pane (I never noticed it there, I don't use the Game Bar much) and found the notification there. I clicked "Dismiss". First I'm going to see if that was enough to stop it (perhaps it keeps popping up because I've never dismissed it in the notification list). If not, I'll try disabling the notifications in Settings. If either of those works, I'll mark this as the answer. Going to wait a day to see if I get any more pop ups. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, definitely disabling notifications. Just got [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mcQC.png) while screen sharing in a work meeting, .

Comment: Disabling that setting seems to have worked. I have not received any new points notifications. (And yes, the specific setting for points does indeed exist.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information, you have to disable the reward notifications on the Android Xbox app separately in addition to the Windows Game Bar.

Comment: Hi nateconq, that was already part of my answer, albeit a vague one. If you can add *how* to do that, it would make for a very helpful addition. Welcome to Arqade!